# How to write roots other than square roots in MathJax?

Tags: support, mathjax

I can't find how to write roots other than square root using MathJax. There doesn't seem to be anything about it on the legendary [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/717872)

These are my best attempts, but they don't look right:

`3\sqrt{64}` $\rightarrow\text{ } 3\sqrt{64}$

`{3}\sqrt{64}` $\rightarrow\text{ } {3}\sqrt{64}$

`^3\sqrt{64}` $\rightarrow\text{ } ^3\sqrt{64}$

What I want to display:

[image: cube root of 64]

How can I properly format it using MathJax? Or is it not possible in MathJax yet?

Comment: `\sqrt[3]{64}` gives you $$\sqrt[3]{64}$$

Comment: It actually is on that legendary page under item $10$

Comment: if the `\sqrt[n]m`$\sqrt[n]m$ didn't exist you would add negative space  to get some approximation of the real deal `{}^3\!\!\!\sqrt{64}`${}^3\!\!\!\sqrt{64}$ also note that you need `{}^3` instead of just `^3` to avoid the previous thing from having a power e.g. `a=^3\sqrt b` vs `a={}^3\sqrt b` $a=^3\sqrt b$ vs $a={}^3\sqrt b$. In fact if the previous thing already has a power then you get an error e.g. `a^3^3\sqrt b` vs `a^3{}^3\sqrt b` $a^3^3\sqrt b $ vs $a^3{}^3\sqrt b$. This is useful if you like writing $a_{ij}{}^{kl}$, ${}^t\!A$, ${}^n C_r$...

Comment: @CalvinKhor thanks!

Comment: @Jyrki yes, that's what I suggested in my comment the other day (on amWhy's answer).

Comment: Sorry, @Gerry. Don't know how I missed your comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `\sqrt[n]{m}` to get the $n$th root of m: $\sqrt[n]{m}.$

Comment: Or, \root3\of{64} $\root3\of{64}$

Comment: @GerryMyerson `$\root{a}\of{x}$` $\root{a}\of{x}$ yes that works too! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
$$\sqrt[3]{64}$$
```

produces

$$\sqrt[3]{64}$$

This is standard LaTeX syntax, see e.g. [this page](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/%7Edwilkins/LaTeXPrimer/FractsRoots.html). It might be confusing since 'sqrt' is an abbreviation of 'square root', but it works nevertheless.